# Java android development starting

Tags: java, android

I wanna start with android programming. I am using eclipse and installed Android SDK. Then in eclipse i installed ADT Plugin, and after that installed every tool and file for 4.2(Jelly Bean) from SDK manager and also installed all extras from SDK manager (expect Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator - because i use AMD). Then when i create android application project i get this problems:

- First, wizard for creating project is not closing after i click finish but it creates app (can see it in package explorer)
- Second, i get errors in MainActivity and Values>styles.xml - In console it gives me errors `No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'`, `No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.`, `No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'`, and these errors show in about 15 lines.

I tried adding `appcompat-v7-24.2.0.javadoc.jar` and `appcompat-v7-24.2.0.source.jar` files in Java Build Path (project settings), but that doesn't work either.

I really do not know what to do. Before i was using Eclipse Neon, and i even tried installing Eclipse Standard and reinstalling android SDK and ADT, but doesn't work. So please at least try to help me. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why don't use `Android Studio`. Its pretty good looking and always updating. Learning `Android` by using `Android Studio` is more easy. So I'll suggest you to use : https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: Google is no longer supporting Eclipse-based Android development, as of the end of 2015. I too strongly recommend that you move to Android Studio.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will uninstall eclipses and everything that refers to android, so i will try everything over again but with android studio

Comment: Just to ask something. Is android studio compatible with AMD processor?

Comment: Dear friend, please take a look at this documentation topic : [getting-started](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/85/getting-started#t=201608221652338270468) and it will help you. GLHF

Comment: @UProduction yes `Android Studio` is compatible with AMD but emulators run faster with Intel because only Intel supports Virtualization; so you can use it much faster with real device or Genymotion when using with AMD (I am using with FX-6300) . And when Instant run is enabled the first build can lock/freeze pc quite a bit

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz thanks. I will try using Genymotion and real device and i will see how does it lay to me.Just to know, i am also using FX-6300 :)

Thanks for all answers guys. I am downloading android studio now, and for that time i am going to read something about it :)

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz "only Intel supports Virtualization" is nonsense. Hardware hypervisor support is standard on AMD x86_64 processors and only enabled on select Intels.

Comment: @chrylis ah can you give some source for me, I found that interesting. Also Genymotion using  VirtualBox; and actually we are using Virtualization with AMD too.

Comment: as @YasinKaçmaz suggested, Android Studio is a way better choice